# Safely store handle along side buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, handle, allocator

I'm writing a custom allocator acting as bridge between regular c++ code and a library performing its own memory management. This library identifies memory locations by a *handle* which we need for all memory management related operations. Think of this handle as a `uint64_t`.

When allocating space for an `T[]` of size `n`, I would like to additionally store this handle in front of the buffer, so that I can retrieve later again from the start address to deallocate the memory.

How can this be done in a **safe** way, i.e. in a way that respects padding requirements etc.?

I believe this code to be potentially unsafe and UB:

```
T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
    void* memory = external_allocate(n*sizeof(T) + sizeof(Handle));
    static_cast<Handle*>(memory)[0] = handle;  // store handle itself (at offset -8):
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&static_cast<Handle*>(memory)[1]);
}

void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) {
    Handle handle = reinterpret_cast<Handle*>(p)[-1];
    external_deallocate(handle);
}
```

Comment: You could use [`alignof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) and a bit of arithmetic to allocate extra memory and pad it so the returned `T*` satisfies `T`'s alignment requirements

Comment: if handle is always going to be a `uint64_t` I don't see a problem. Someone correct me if i'm wrong.
My only question would be *are you sure you want to do this?* to me it would be more straight-forward to just maintain a hash table somewhere mapping the allocated pointers (casted to `void*` say) to their handles.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I considered a hashtable, but for me it seems rather inelegant, if the task can be solved in principle with a single addition and memory lookup.